# Vertical centering with fixed header

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment, fixed

I have a page with fixed header. I need the whole page to be verticaly centered in a way that header is always fixed but the whole page is verticaly centered.

I can't figure out, how it can be done, because it takes more than just messing around with negative margins and absolute positioning (at least I wasn't able to find a solution that works...). I created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjjcT/1/)...

System wants me to add some code so here is the basic structure you can see in the jsFiddle

```
<body>
    <div id="header"><h1>HEADER</h1></div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>This is some content.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So you want the header at the top and the rest of the content vertically centered? Your statement, "This is some content. I want it to be vertically centered along with the fixed header" is confusing.

Comment: Ok my bad, I changed that. The header should not be at the top unless there is enough content (i.e. page has a scrollbar)

Comment: Do you want the `content` div to be in the middle of the view port? or in the middle of the remaining space after the `header`?

Comment: Never mind, I've posted a solution for both scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you want the content to be vertically centered in the space that is left after the header: see that [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/CcneA/) *Tested on:* IE10, IE9, IE8, Chrome, FF, Safari

2) If you want the content to be vertically centered in the view port regardless of the header: see that [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/CcneA/1/) *Tested on:* IE10, IE9, IE8, Chrome, FF, Safari

it's the same HTML markup for both examples, the difference is in the CSS (the second one is simpler, but the result is uglier)

**HTML**

```
<div id="header"><h1>YOUR HEADER</h1></div>
<div id="container"><!-- only that container shall be scrollable -->
    <span class="centerer"></span><!-- this comment is important
    --><div id="content">
        YOUR CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

**Notice**: the comment is important, because new line is treated like whitespace between `inline-block`s element. which results as a space gap in the output.
with the use of the comment, the code is still readable, but there is no white-space between the elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to use this for.. This works in modern browsers but not in all browsers..

The problem is usually that elements do not have a fixed height. We do not know the screen height in pixels so the height has to be dynamic. Older browser do not give elements a certain height until they are filled.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mz6hy/25/

Tested this in Chrome, Safari and Firefox..

```
<head>
    <style>
    body
    {
        width           : 100%;
        background      : #fff;
        margin          : 60px 0 -60px 0;
    }
    h1
    {
        text-align      : center;
    }
    #content 
    {
        position        : absolute;
        top             : 50%;
        height          :100px;
        margin-top      :-50px;
    }
    #footer 
    {
        position        :absolute;
        top             :100%;
        height          :50px;
        margin-top      :-50px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HEADER</h1>
    <div id="content">
        <p>
            This is some content.<br/>
            I want it to be verticaly centered along with the fixed header. The header should always be fixed, but it should be placed in a way that the overall page is verticaly centered.
        </p>
        <p>
            Some more content
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Editional content</div>
</body>
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to work. If I add more content so that the page becomes scrollable, the header isn't fixed and scrolls also...

Comment: Ok, then make the h1's `position: fixed` this will make it relative to the browser window rather than the body that scrolls. You can also do this with the footer if you want. But what would be the content? What is the purpose of this page? Maybe there's a better solution if you share some details. For example you can use Bootstrap as a way to quickly make more complex layout quite easily.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved now very simply with flexbox and a measurement of `100vh` on the main container.

**CSS:**

```
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
display: -webkit-flex;
justify-content: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
```

See full demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f8syhrkv/